# Application rejected on myapps.developer.ubuntu.com. What can I do?

Tags: software-center, application-development, ppa, development

I submitted a desktop application on myapps.developer.ubuntu.com long time ago. But it was rejected today with the following reason:

```
This package submission process is now deprecated.
```

To provide my application I have a PPA and this was what I have submitted as text file for 'My Application' (where the application should be uploaded):

```
PPA owner name: Holger Seelig
Email: holger.seelig@yahoo.de
Application name: titania
App PPA location: https://launchpad.net/~holger-seelig/+archive/ubuntu/titania
```

The application should be provided with no costs and GPL licence.

The point is, that it is not clear for me, even if I have carefully read all help pages on dev.ubuntu.com, how to submit a freeware application.

What do I have to upload? The description of the PPA, a Debian source package, or what else?

Do I have to delete my application now and create a new application with the same name, or can I change something?

What can I do now?